# using Flex on Gmail emails

Tags: html, css, flexbox, gmail

I am trying to produce a resposive table in an email template using flex and flex proerties.

The email template uses inline flex styling. For some reason, Gmail is removing one of the properties.

```
div class="table" style="display: -webkit-flex; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: 0 0 3em 0; padding: 0;">
```

The line above, when i inspect this is firebug, when I am in Gmail, it removes the "flex-wrap: wrap;" property. Any ideas why? How do i resolve this. I tried adding an important to the proeprty, but that also does not make the property appear.

Please help?

Comment: Gmail does not support Flex. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/flexbox/flex/

Comment: Here is a nice article about use of flex in html email which may be useful. But testing in email clients is must. https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1500-using-flexbox-in-an-email